# (A)wait for class to finish instantiate

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task

I try to wait for the class to be finished with instantiate.
My architecture is the following. Cook is inheriade from CookChief.
And if I instantiate cook, CookChief is creating himself, but CookChief is calling 1 other class named Cookhelper the cookhelper is waiting for a input and for this input method i want to wait in Cook.
The thing is iam creating this in MVVM Galasoft and my entry point is the CookViewmodel, with a relaycommand.

In the code below you can see my architecture. To say it short I want to wait until this  bool processed = await Task.Run(() => ValidateForDeviceId()); is finished.

My first step was to outsource the constructer of each class. And create a init method. 
This is my code:

```
public CookViewModel()
    {
        startCookButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(Cook);
    }


    private async Task Cook()
    {
      cook.Init();
    }



public class Cook : CookChief
{
     public Cook()
    {

    }

    public async Task Init()
    {
      await this.CookChiefInit();
       //here I want to wait until CookChiefInit is finished
       Cooking();
    }

    public void Cooking()
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Input received");
    }
}
```

Now the Cookchief:

```
    public Cookchief()
    {

    }

    protected async Task CookchiefInit()
    {
        this.Cookhelper = new Cookhelper();
        Cookhelper.CookHelperInit();
    }
```

And in the CookHelper we do this:

```
    public CookHelper()
    {

    }

    public void CookHelperInit()
    {
        this.driverWindow = new DriverWindow();
        startProc();
    }

    private async void startProc()
    {
        ShowOrCloseDriverWindow(true);
        //this is the task what we wait for before we can repeat
        bool processed = await Task.Run(() => ValidateForDeviceId());
        if(processed)
        {
            ShowOrCloseDriverWindow(false);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("DriverError");
        }
    }

    private bool ValidateForDeviceId()
    {
        for (; ; )
        {
            this.deviceId = Input.deviceId;
            if (deviceId > 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I think you want to [do async work in constuctors?](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html)

Comment: What's the problem? You're already calling `await` on `this.CookChiefInit();`. What is or is not happening that does not meet your expectations?

Comment: The problem is that the await did not wait for the Task. The method Cooking() is called before the task has finished working.

Comment: You code should be waiting where you specified. The problem might be you have a mixed bag of async/sync calls. First thing to do is make sure you're `await`ing every `async` call in this process. Add an await to `cook.Init();` in `CookViewModel.Cook()`. Also, await `Cookhelper.CookHelperInit();` in `CookChief.CookchiefInit()`. Convert `CookHelper.CookHelperInit()` to an `async` method, then await `startProc();` in `CookHelper.CookHelperInit()`.

Comment: Thanks you solved my problem!

Comment: @JulianK. glad to help. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the discussion in the comments, the problem here was that the initialization routine mixed synchronous and asynchronous methods and calls. Additionally, some `async` methods were called without the `await` keyword. The solution was to make all calls asynchronous and `await` them.

`cook.Init()` needs an `await`:

```
private async Task Cook()
{
    await cook.Init();
}
```

In `CookchiefInit()`, the `CookHelperInit()` call needs to be `await`ed:

```
protected async Task CookchiefInit()
{
    this.Cookhelper = new Cookhelper();
    Cookhelper.CookHelperInit();
}
```

In order to `await` `CookHelperInit()`, it needs to be made asynchronous. The `startProc()` call is to an `async` method, so it must also be awaited:

```
public async Task CookHelperInit()
{
    this.driverWindow = new DriverWindow();
    await startProc();
}
```

Comment: A good rule of thumb for consistency is to append `Async` to the name of any method that potentially needs to be awaited, i.e. `await cook.InitAsync()`

Comment: @Felipe indeed it is, however the original poster appeared to have significant trouble understanding the core concepts of `async`/`await`. In order to make the answer as simple for them to follow as possible, I re-used their exact method names and simply added `async`/`await` where necessary. If you feel the answer could be improved in a meaningful way by adding `Async` to the method names, you're more than welcome to add your own answer.